# Create css circles connected by line

Tags: html, css

I need to do this kind of slider that is just three circles connected by a line and with a description below each circle:

[image]

But at the moment I just have this:

[image]

And this is the code I used to make that:

```
            <div
              class="
                text-center
                my-5
                px-5
                d-flex
                align-items-center
                justify-content-between
                slider-container
              "
            >
              <div class="slider-item">
                <i
                  class="
                    icon-circle
                    fs-16 fs-md-20
                    d-inline-block
                    text-gray-300
                  "
                ></i>
                <p class="m-0 font-RobotoBold1 fs-10 fs-md-12 mt-2">
                  Selecciona <br />
                  cantidad
                </p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <i
                  class="
                    icon-circle
                    fs-16 fs-md-20
                    d-inline-block
                    text-gray-300
                  "
                ></i>
                <p class="m-0 font-RobotoBold1 fs-10 fs-md-12 mt-2">
                  Selecciona <br />
                  destino
                </p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <i
                  class="
                    icon-circle
                    fs-16 fs-md-20
                    d-inline-block
                    text-gray-300
                  "
                ></i>
                <p class="m-0 font-RobotoBold1 fs-10 fs-md-12 mt-2">
                  Confirma <br />
                  transferencia
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
```

This is the css code:

```
.slider-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider-container::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  Content: "";
  Background-color: grey;
  height: 1px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Anyone knows how to make that line behind the circles and that doesn't exceed them?

Comment: What a messy markup. Is this tailwindcss? It's horrible to look at, must be a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: In the company I work we use bootstrap and we make our own css sheets to use it. I know, it could be a nightmare if you don't know the project.

Comment: Since each item takes up 1/3rd of the container, the line would need to be 2/3rds the width of the container. `.slider-container::before {left:16.67%; right:16.67%;}`

Comment: @Ouroborus Always a bad idea to create solutions tailored to exactly **one** use-case.

Comment: @connexo It's an example, provided to understand what the problem is, as well as solving the specific issue. It'll be up to OP to convert that into a broadly applicable solution if necessary. The narrow use case is also why I didn't provide it as a formal answer. If you think you can convert it into a broader solution and provide an answer based on that, feel free. The solution you did provide doesn't seem applicable given the constraints OP has.

Comment: @Ouroborus I don't see any contraints prohibiting the use of my solution in OP's question.

Comment: @connexo They did mention in the comments that they use a framework. Answering "don't use a framework" isn't typically useful in such cases. Also, it occurs to me that there is a pure css solution that fits within OP's constraints, answers OP's specific question, and meets your own need for flexibility.

Comment: @Ouroborus That is just my standpoint on CSS frameworks. OP is free to use the solution alongside any CSS framework they choose. I won't ever use one in my answers, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sidenote: *This is why I would never use tailwindcss or the likes. You don't need it, and it totally ruins the HTML.*

Now compare the markup you have with the markup below - which is a) much, much more concise, b) using only a single CSS class and c) using the proper semantic elements for the job.

It also works for 2 or 4 or 7 items. Sure it needs some refinement regarding size and color of the active circle, but that should be an easy adjustment for you.

The only restriction of this solution is that your page background-color needs to be solid and be matched by the background-color of the `::after` elements.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.steplist').forEach(steplist => {
  steplist.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target.nodeName !== 'LI') return;
    const items = event.target.closest('.steplist').querySelectorAll('li');
    for (const item of items) {
      item.classList.toggle('active', item === event.target);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
*, ::after, ::before { box-sizing: border-box; }

.steplist {
  border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  list-style-type: none;
  gap: 7em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  --circle-radius: 8px;
}

.steplist li {
  color: #999;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: calc(5px + var(--circle-radius)) 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.steplist li::before {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: calc(2 * var(--circle-radius));
  width: calc(2 * var(--circle-radius));
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.steplist .active {
  color: black;
}

.steplist .active::before {
  background-color: green;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(0,255,0,.25);
}

.steplist li:first-child::after {
  background-color: white;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  top: -2px;
  left: calc(-50% - var(--circle-radius));
}

.steplist li:last-child::after {
  background-color: white;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  top: -2px;
  left: calc(50% + var(--circle-radius));
}

.circle-big {
  --circle-radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<ol class="steplist">
  <li>Point 1<br>whatever</li>
  <li>Point 2<br>whatever</li>
  <li>Point 3<br>whatever</li>
</ol>

<br><br><br>

<ol class="steplist circle-big">
  <li>Point 1<br>whatever</li>
  <li>Point 2<br>whatever</li>
  <li>Point 3<br>whatever</li>
  <li>Point 4<br>whatever</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This solution is amazing, Thank you!

Comment: @connexo Amazing solution, any idea how to make it vertically?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solve the case with this code, I added the custom classes so you can understand what are those, and in the slider-container:before, the formula 'top: calc(50% - 22px)', the px can change depending of the size of the screen. :

```css
/* slider css code */

.slider-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider-container::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 22px);
  right: 65px;
  left: 65px;
  content: "";
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
  height: 1px;
  z-index: -1;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .slider-container::before {
    top: calc(50% - 22px);
    right: 60px;
    left: 60px;
  }
}


/* this are custom css classes we use at work */

.wi-12 {
  width: 12px;
}

.he-12 {
  height: 12px;
}

.wi-24 {
  width: 24px;
}

.he-24 {
  height: 24px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .wi-md-20 {
    width: 20px;
  }
  .he-md-20 {
    height: 20px;
  }
  .wi-md-30 {
    width: 30px;
  }
  .he-md-30 {
    height: 30px;
  }
  .wi-md-100 {
    width: 100px;
  }
}

.wi-70 {
  width: 70px;
}

.bg-green-700 {
  background-color: #00bf79;
}

.bg-gray-300 {
  background-color: #bababa;
}

.bor-rounded-full {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.font-Roboto {
  font-family: "Roboto";
}

.fs-10 {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.fs-md-12 {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="
                text-center
                mt-md-4
                px-4
                d-flex
                align-items-center
                justify-content-between
                slider-container
                mb-md-3
              ">
  <div class="slider-item wi-70 wi-md-100">
    <div class="
                    wi-24
                    he-24
                    wi-md-30
                    he-md-30
                    bor-rounded-full
                    d-inline-flex
                    justify-content-center
                    align-items-center
                  " style="
                   background: rgba(0, 191, 121, 0.3);
                  ">
      <div class="wi-12 he-12 wi-md-20 he-md-20 bg-green-700 bor-rounded-full d-inline-block"></div>
    </div>
    <p class="m-0 font-Roboto fs-10 fs-md-12 mt-2">
      Selecciona <br /> cantidad
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-item wi-70 wi-md-100">
    <div class="
                    wi-24
                    he-24
                    wi-md-30
                    he-md-30
                    bor-rounded-full
                    d-inline-flex
                    justify-content-center
                    align-items-center
                  ">
      <div class="wi-12 he-12 wi-md-20 he-md-20 bg-gray-300 bor-rounded-full d-inline-block"></div>
    </div>
    <p class="m-0 font-Roboto fs-10 fs-md-12 mt-2">
      Selecciona <br /> destino
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-item wi-70 wi-md-100">
    <div class="
                    wi-24
                    he-24
                    wi-md-30
                    he-md-30
                    bor-rounded-full
                    d-inline-flex
                    justify-content-center
                    align-items-center
                  ">
      <div class="wi-12 he-12 wi-md-20 he-md-20 bg-gray-300 bor-rounded-full d-inline-block"></div>
    </div>
    <p class="m-0 font-Roboto fs-10 fs-md-12 mt-2">
      Confirma <br /> transferencia
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```