# Change carousel indicators to circles Bootstarp 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

All the available solutions in Stackoverflow only work for Bootstrap 4. I want to know a way to change Carousel indicators to circles instead of rectangles

I tried this:

```
.carousel-indicators [data-bs-target] {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  width: 10px; /* change width */
  height: 10px; /* change height */
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 100%; /* add border-radius */
}
```

but got this result:

[image]

Changing the height property has absolutely no effect on the indicators

Comment: Looking for something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70630336/create-css-circles-connected-by-line/70630451#70630451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just checked the carousel indicators in Bootstarp , setting proper with and height along with proper border radius giving me circled indicatores.
Please check the edited below code this may help you.  this was working for me or can you share a demo link to the problem

```
.carousel-indicators [data-bs-target] {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    text-indent: -999px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    opacity: .5;
    transition: opacity .6s ease;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Still getting really stretched ellipses

Comment: could you give me a link to the issue so that i can check, may be in fiddle or codepen.